# How do you make linked resources in Eclipse metadata system-independent

Tags: eclipse, git

I use eclipse to develop my project, with git. I use 2 different system : Windows and Linux. Sometimes I work on Win, sometimes on Linux.

In my project I have a linked resources to a Google Drive folder.

On windows, the folder is D:\GoogleDrive and on Linux /mysuer/GDrive.

I configured the linked resources under windows. So in my .project I have a direct reference to D:\GoogleDrive\myfolder.

So, if I commit the .project, when I checkout under linux, I will have the path relative to windows.

I think may be I can ignore the .project but I don't know it is really better. What I risk to lose ?

What do you do yourself ?

Thanks

Comment: I would probably not version the `.project` file, as it is specific to a certain development environment.  You can add it to `.gitignore`, unless you've already added it, in which case you'll need to `git rm 'cached'` it first.

Comment: Project files are irrelevant with your source code. Definitely add it to your gitignore as Tim said.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't generate the project files and do settings that you want the same on all development machines like code style settings and so on, it is perfectly valid to check in the IDE metadata.

You should just leverage the Feature "Path Variables" that is provided by IntelliJ IDEA and now also Eclipse: http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fcpathvars.htm

You then just set this path variable in your local Eclipse workspaces and define your linked resource relative to this path variable as the linked doku describes.